# Play2 GlobalSettings.getControllerInstance concurrency issue

Tags: concurrency, playframework-2.0

I am having a concurrency issue fetching controllers from my Play Global Object.

Env:

- Play2.2.1 for Java
- Spring Managed Controllers/Actions
- Global object which overrides getControllerInstance

I am sending two requests concurrently and noticed that sometimes the request ends up getting the wrong controller
Example:

Request X gets Controller X
Request X gets Controller X
Request X gets Controller X

Request Y gets Controller Y  //new request gets its controller

Request X gets Controller Y  //new x request gets y's controller should not have happened.

Request Y gets Controller Y

Request Y gets Controller Y

Each request has a different dispatcher thread.

Here is a github app to reproduce the issue https://github.com/SaadKhawaja/play2-concurrency-test.

Please read the README file it has the steps to reproduce the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your action is singleton, but needs to be prototype scoped. Play injects the controller into the action for each request, so a singleton action will cause concurrency issues.